# What is the ruling if a woman finds that she is pregnant during her iddah period?

Tags: iddah, pregnancy

What is the ruling if a woman finds that she is pregnant during her iddah period? Does the iddah continue on with the 3 months rule or does it continue until the pregnancy is complete?

Comment: I assume you mean that she realized she was pregnant during her 'iddah.

Comment: No. She falls pregnant during her iddah

Comment: This needs further information. Please consider editing your post because falling pregnant in 'iddah may mean either a reconciliation happened or something unlawfull. In any case i doubt that the actually given answer adresses this case.

Answer (score 1):

All the scholars agree that the iddah of a divorced woman that is pregnant ends when she gives birth because Allah says in the Quran:

> “And for those who are pregnant (whether they are divorced or their husbands are dead), their ‘Iddah (prescribed period) is until they lay down their burden”
>
> ([al-Talaaq 65:4](https://quran.com/65/4))

Source: [Islam Q&A](http://web.archive.org/web/20150325101052/http://islamqa.info:80/en/27622)

Comment: Could you provide evidence for the statement that all scholars agree on that even if she doesn't want to?

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'even if she doesn't want to'?